# f# keyword use and using

Tags: f#

I am trying to use `System.Data.Sqlite` with F#. In C#, I have code like

```
 using (DbTransaction dbTrans = con.BeginTransaction()) {
     using (SQLiteCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand()) {
         //blahblah
     }
     dbTrans.Commit();
 }
```

But in F#, when I use the similiar two `using` above I got error of `the type bool is not compatible with the type IDisposable`...
**EDIT** I am really sorry for my question. `use` would work in F# case. I just dont know how to close/delete my quesetions.

Comment: I don't know whether you really need to delete the question. It isn't a bad question: it got an upvote, and two decent answers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

in f# it's

```
use dbTrans = new con.BeginTransaction ()
```

and

```
use cmd = con.CreateCommand()
```

these will dispose when your function ends

Answer (score 25):

To add some details - if you need to explicitly mark the scope where command is valid (to get exactly the same behavior as in your C# example, where `cmd` id disposed of before calling `Commit`) you can write:

```
use dbTrans = con.BeginTransaction()
( use cmd = con.CreateCommand()
  cmd.BlahBlahBlah() )
dbTrans.Commit()
```

The scope is just a part of expression where the symbol is defined, so you can make it explicit using parentheses.

`using` is just an F# function that you could use before special syntax using `use` was added. Just FYI, the syntax looks like this:

```
using (con.BeginTransaction()) (fun dbTrans ->
  using (con.CreateCommand()) (fun cmd ->
    cmd.BlahBlahBlah() )
dbTrans.Commit() )
```

Writing the code using `use` is definitely a better idea (but you can define your functions like `using` to encapsulate more interesting behavior - e.g. transaction).