# Why is use better than using?

Tags: f#, dispose, idisposable, resource-management

According to the last sentence on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233240.aspx) `use` is to be preferred over `using`. I've heard it elsewhere ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973795/f-keyword-use-and-using/4975622#4975622), for example). Why is this? I realize `use` was added later. But what's the difference? On the surface, `using` seems more useful because you can control when `Dispose()` is called, and you can explicitly ignore the bound value (e.g., `(fun _ -> ...)`) if needed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think that the reason for preferring `use` is just that the syntax is simpler. Many other language constructs could be expressed as functions (e.g. `try .. with`, `for`, `while`, ...). If the language designers added a simpler syntax, why not use it...

As I wrote in the [earlier answer you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973795/f-keyword-use-and-using/4975622#4975622), you can precisely control the scope even when using `use`. (And this way, you can use it even in constructors of <strike>object expressions</strike> class declarations.) But most of the time, the automatic behavior is just fine (which makes the construct simpler than `using` in C#).

Whether you'll use `use` or `using` in situations where you need to control the scope explicitly is a matter of personal taste. If you don't like the explicit scoping of `use` (which looks a bit weird, I admit, but works fine for me), you can use `using`.

**EDIT:** In a class declaration, you cannot for example write:

```
type Foo() =
  use a = new Whatever()
  // ...
```

because the scope of `a` would be (possibly) the whole lifetime of the instance. (Although I think this could be useful and it could add automatic implementation of `IDisposable` to your type). If you use `using`, you don't get this sort of trouble.

Comment: I experimented with object expressions and couldn't figure out the limitation you mentioned. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Daniel: Sorry, I meant to say class declarations - not object expressions!

Comment: I'm still not finding the limitation. `using` seems to work fine within a constructor.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood. I thought the limitation applies to `using`. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 21):

You can control when dispose is called with `use` as well, just by using usual scoping contructs (like parens or `begin`-`end`), e.g.

```
let F() =
    let x = 4
    (
        use file = System.IO.File.Open("foo.xml", System.IO.FileMode.Append)
        let z = 4
        printfn "file still open here"
    )
    printfn "file was already closed/disposed"
```

But I think this is rarely useful.  I think it is also rare to not want to name/utilize the `IDisposable` object.  `use` is more syntactically convenient, and 95% of the time does what you need, so I think that's why it's preferred.

Comment: The syntactic oddity of this seems like yet another reason to favor `using`. Do you know if they produce different IL?

Comment: I expect they produce similar IL, though I don't know or care.  As for the syntactical oddity, again, no one write code like this, because no one cares whether `Dispose` is called two lines before the end of the function or just at the end of the function.  Scenarios where it matters are extremely rare.  Just use `use`.

Comment: One scenario where it does require you to write something _after_ the `use` scope ends is if you need to properly test for a released object (a locked file being writable again), or for instance with semaphores. Still, just wrapping the `use` in one function and call your after-release code after calling that function would suffice, and scoping like in this example is not needed.

Comment: It's interesting to note that everybody seems to be missing the `use ... in ...` syntax to control scoping. I didn't even know that you can do that with parens like you show; I thought the only way is to use `in`.

For example: https://gist.github.com/jwosty/cfbf9cc67e9d051f2194895d37298cf9

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I prefer `use` to `using` for the same reason that I prefer

```
let a = some_expr
some_stuff_with_a
```

to

```
(fun a -> some_stuff_with_a) some_expr
```

With the binding form, you can typically avoid a set of parentheses, and the association between the identifier and the value that it's being bound to are closer in space and easier to see.

Answer (score 0):

An example against `use` is better then `using`:

`using` is better than `use` as `using` can be written in one line while `use` cannot.

Example,
`xx` is a function returning a value by a function fct from a resource which is opened by `yy` using given parameter `p`.

```
let xx p = using (yy(p)) (fun resource-> fct resource)     // <-- this is OK

let xx p  = (use resource = yy(p); fct resource)           // <-- this is Not OK
```

Comment: You need to use `in`, as in:
`let xx p = (use resource = yy(p) in fct resource)`.