# scope of 'use' keyword using F#

Tags: scope, f#

Assume the following code:

```
let fn () =
  use a = new System.IO.StreamWriter ("d:\\test.txt")
  a

let b = fn ()
b.Write "t"
```

It gives following error:

> ObjectDisposedException: Cannot write to a closed TextWriter.

Why is that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`use` is scoped to the function `fn` so when `a` is returned it also disposed.

The easiest way to cure this is:

```
let fn () =
  let a = new System.IO.StreamWriter ("d:\\test.txt")
  a

let main() = 
  use b = fn ()
  b.Write "t"
main()
```

Answer (score 5):

To add a bit more to Robert's (correct) answer: you can achieve even finer control over the scope of `use` with scoping constructs (parentheses or begin/end). See Brian's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046567/why-is-use-better-than-using/5046680#5046680) to a related question.

Comment: Thanks, I have to admit I didn't know that was possible.

Answer (score 2):

The resource will be disposed as soon as the variable (in your case `a`) goes out of scope.

This means that after the call to `fn` the `StreamWriter` will already be disposed.

Comment: And why does it not wait until I stop using 'b' when 'b' = 'a'?

Comment: Because it looks at the **variable** `a` and doesn't "follow" the value held by that variable.